# Unity - 2019.3 Mobile Android APK fails on load

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2019.3.0f1 and I am building under Android platform. I created a new Universal RP project, then inside it, I create a new scene with a simple plane and a sphere. I removed the default sample scene and added my new one to the build settings.
Below are my Player Settings:

[image]

Also, since Unity has issue to find Android NDK installation which comes with it, I installed NDK and SDK manually as described [there](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-ndk-missing.689122/).

Then, I simply build the project. I have two APKs - one for 32 and one for 64 architecture. None of them works however - when I start either of them, it quits even before showing me unity splash screen.

[This is the logcat](https://gist.github.com/angel1st/9efad82a5400e3b153f1b3fdbe92ef99), collected from an Android device (ARM64 architecture apk):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that it is a Unity 2019.3 bug related to minification step, when apk is building. The workaround ATM is to select **None** for both **Release** and **Debug** in **Minify** settings group. These can be found on "Project Settings / Player / Android / Publishing Settings" screen, at the very bottom.